# Google Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 m no longer passing the selected value of grid on direct server call

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

This stopped work with latest Chrome version

3rd party button with server call OnClick="SaveLists"

3rd party (Obout) grid on server side

Me.grid.SelectedRecords.Item(0).item("name").ToString returns as nothing

this works just fine on autopostback in the page load sub...but not on the direct server call. Continues to work just fine on IE.